# EntitySet is not defined in the EntityContainer. EF WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I've created a new view in SQL Server & added it to my model.edmx. In my view model I'm querying the view...

```
 private void LoadPublicationsList()
    {
        using (var conn = new EntityConnection("name=ISESEntities"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            EntityCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT VALUE t FROM ISESEntities.vwPublications AS t";

            blah blah
```

When I compile i get an exception 'The EntitySet 'vwPublications' is not defined in the EntityContainer 'ISESEntities'. Near simple identifier,line 1, column 34.'

All other tables/views in my model work no problem and are in the same EntityContainer:IsesEntities.

The view is defined in the EntityContainer:IsesEntities in the Model browser, everything seems fine. I've rebuilt the edmx, restarted VS. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `vwPublications` must be the name of the `ObjectSet` in the context.

Comment: Yes when I new up an Entity object (ISESEntities) my new view isn't an ObjectSet. How do I add the new view to the existing Entity? Thanks

Comment: You said "added it to my model.edmx", so the view should be in there as a property of type `ObjectSet<>` or `DbSet<>`.

Comment: Yes, In my model bowser under EntityContainer:ISESEntities, the new view is there, also there in the edmx designer. However, in my view model when I new up a ISESEntities object, the new view isn't there as ObjectSet...

Comment: Maybe you have to poke the code generation tool to regenerate the model? (Although this should happen when you save the model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great, thanks Gert.

Your comment led me to notice that because my EF Model is in a separate project within the solution I just needed to refresh the reference to my Model project in the application. Then the Entity object picked up the changes. Doh! you live & learn...